# Laravel 3 And AngularJs Feching Resutls From Database And Passing it to View

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Before i start i would like to tell i am a begginer and i would like to learn more.
I was reading a lot of tutorials but i never found and answer to my question.

Before we start i know what is rest and how it works.

What i dont know is how to create it with angularjs and laravel.

What i think about is, i have a database with mobile phones, and information about them (this is just an example in my mind)

Laravel Controller

```
<?php

class Phones_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;    

    public function get_index()
    {

    }    

    public function post_index()
    {

    }    

    public function get_show()
    {

    }    

    public function get_edit()
    {

    }    

    public function get_new()
    {

    }    

    public function put_update()
    {

    }    

    public function delete_destroy()
    {

    }

}
```

And here is the part where im clueless.

So the get/how function retunrs the phone beeing viewd by id in json

function

```
public function get_show($id)
    {
        $phones = Phone::find($id);
        return Response::eloquent($phones);
    }
```

So when i browse in the browser to `http://mysite.com/phones/show/1` i see the json objects

Okay so this is what i mainly dont understand, when i am here  `http://mysite.com/phones/show/1, how can i pass the resutls to a view?

I know how to use `http request` in angular, i dont get do i need to call the show function twice?

**Example**

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/phones/show/:id'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
$scope.phones = data;
}).
```

And create a nother laravel controller function to show the actually view the with the results?

If someone could point this out form me would be happy

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And create a nother laravel controller function to show the actually view the with the results?

Angular JS is your "view" - Laravel just sends the JSON results, which Angular grabs - and then Angular decides what to do with it.

If you want Laravel to be your "view" - then you dont want/need Angular - your duplicating your work/effort.

So in other words - Angular is your "front end" - it handles all the user experience, UI, requests etc. When Angular needs some data, like a user profile - it goes over to the "back end" (Laravel) and says "hey - can you give me user X profile". Laravel responds with JSON "no worries - here it is".

Angular then takes that JSON data - and displays it however you want.

Comment: PS: Gave you the 300 bounty revard for taking so much time aswering my questions, thanks :)