# Send query params to server from angularjs routes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am using AngularJS for my client side framework. Using the routeprovider, I want to sent query params to my templateURL for processing. Basically my templateURL is  a server side php script which will generate HTML.

Now routeprovider is not sending query params to my server side code. I am getting blank values for all such params.

If my approach is wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against having your server render your HTML for you... but I suppose if you had to do things this way, you could just leverage ng-include:

When you set up your route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/route/:id', {
    template: '<div ng-include="/Some/Url?id={{id}}"></div>',
    controller: 'FooCtrl'
});
```

Then your controller:

```
app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
   $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The way Angular is meant to be used is that the client requests the content as JSON from the server (with the [$http module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)) and then the HTML is built on the client-side. See [what-is-the-point-of-angularjs-routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909003/what-is-the-point-of-angularjs-routes?rq=1) I also highly recommend the [official tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, I am modifying my approach as you suggested.